# How to create usable URL for opening document?

Tags: c#, ios, url, pdf, xamarin.ios

**The general problem:** I have some code that needs a URL to a PDF file.  It seems to work for URLs I find online, but not the ones I create myself.

For example, when I use a random URL from [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) it works fine, but when I try to generate a URL from either [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/) or [Amazon Cloud Drive](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive) it does not work.

**Example URLs:**

These links open harmless PDF files.  Please try it:

- [Xamarin (works fine)](http://docs.xamarin.com/sites/xamarin.com/files/pdfs/sqlite-18883.pdf)
- [DropBox (does not work)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1623vrn5atoejz/1_1.pdf)
- [Amazon Cloud Drive (does not work)](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share?s=NyExJ494SuQnE22PwFVliQ)

As you see, in a browser (I have used Chrome to test) you will get the PDF documents to open, but not without some kind of context (except for the Xamarin one).

**The code:** I am developing in `MonoTouch` and I am using a component called [mTouch PDF Reader](http://www.mtouch-pdfreader.com).  The code is simply:

```
var documentViewController = new DocumentViewController (1, "Some name here", "http://someurlhere.pdf");
ActivateController (documentViewController);
```

This opens a nice PDF reader inside my app, but, as I can't use my own created URLs this does not help me.  This is a 3rd party library so I can't look at the code.  By the way, when I use one of my URLs, the code crashes with a `System.NullReferenceException` with this stacktrace:

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.NSArray.FromNativeObjects (items={MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController[1]}, count=1) in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/shared/Foundation/NSArray.cs:109
MonoTouch.Foundation.NSArray.FromNativeObjects (items={MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController[1]}) in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/shared/Foundation/NSArray.cs:96
MonoTouch.Foundation.NSArray.FromNSObjects (items={MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController[1]}) in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/shared/Foundation/NSArray.cs:48
MonoTouch.UIKit.UIPageViewController.SetViewControllers (viewControllers={MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController[1]}, direction=MonoTouch.UIKit.UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated=false, completionHandler={MonoTouch.UIKit.UICompletionHandler}) in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIPageViewController.g.cs:144
mTouchPDFReader.Library.Views.Core.DocumentViewController.ViewDidLoad () in 
MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain () in 
MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (args={string[0]}, principalClassName=(null), delegateClassName="AppDelegate") in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
Exam936.Application.Main (args={string[0]}) in /Users/EdGriMac/Dropbox/Quiz/Code/Exam926/Exam936/Main.cs:16
```

**The frustration:**
Is there a specific way to create URLs that work in this way?  It does seem like DropBox does something different as it sort of iFrames the document or something.  I don't know what Amazon Cloud Drive does.  What has Xamarin done?  Is it, as pointed out in the comments, because of `http` vs `https`?

I am completely lost.  Am I missing something simple?  Do you have any other way to create URLs to suggest?  Googling this is really difficult as I continue to hit examples of how to share a URL in DropBox and so on...

By the way, I do not want to have the documents as part of the app as this means I will have to create a new version of the app just to change something in a document.

**Update 1:** I have added links above.  I will try some other suggestions later and will leave more updates.  Thanks in advance for any further suggestions!

**Update 2:** I have used [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to look at the response on each of the URLs.  The Xamarin URL has `Content-Type: application/pdf` while both DropBox and Amazon Cloud Drive has `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`.  This explains a lot.  I will try andersr's suggestion later today as I do have a web server to put files on.

**Update 3** When I put the PDF file on my Amazon EC2 server, created a virtual directory under my web site in IIS, the URL to my website + virtual directory + filename worked!  Turns out the `Content-Type` had to be `application/pdf` for the `mTouch PDF Reader` to open it through a URL.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you could give us an actual example.  If I had to guess, I'd start by checking the headers of the HTTP response to see if the MIME type is set correctly.  You could also try downloading the file from the server using WebClient to verify that the file is transferring correctly and is not corrupt.  You could also contact MTouch support.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for your suggestions!  I have added example URLs.  I will try your other suggestions as well ...

Comment: From the few examples you posted, it looks like `http:` links works fine, but `https:` fails. do we have a pattern here ?

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix I have noticed that too (but seem to have removed the comment after I updated the question).  But, if that is the case, how or where can I create an URL with `http` instead of `https`?

Comment: you can **create** it, but it probably won't work

Comment: Dropbox and Amazon are not providing direct links to the PDF.  You need to find a different host for your files.  I know that Amazon's S3 service will allow you to direct link to files.

Comment: @Jason Yes, you are correct.  Amazon and DropBox wraps html around the PDF file to add extra functionality, which ruins the `Content-Type` that I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the first two URLS, link directly to the PDF files, but the latter one, ie. the one on Amazon Cloud Drive links to a page which again links to the PDF. I suggest the following potential solutions:

1. Find a reliable way to extract the direct url to the document on cloud drive. The link to the document is not the one you provided, but this: [link](https://zcd-00.s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/A3N7NHKF1JMVO9/XR4tJbM/knp30lALVCx8YBdy%2B4AiiXCBFhkYigRQKVR2Gv4iS6C3u4g0LjWLYbsSUXMDNJYG%2Bwa7Jz3VQbdjmdOHCKZg%2B4gc4WCYz6n8NVtenG2ftkZEJBX/Cod/0tdt/cWOfI24h2QU2q4NNmDth/rsaALIvBnNF%2BELeAr4ICJfNhioZ0AneiX4COoJRzGa%2BjyS4hXEOLgAAaMpCNNHjzOxrQxPNpF3F0wQpDKYiJza6LpZG7xloOpkZRCDkyPgCOfu8a5CK7aXy55pNdsyh9tzwehxBwPGPOi0D9CT32TWpqBbew%2BtMzEnNEOB8EVP?Expires=1381393006&response-expires=Thu%2C%2010%20Oct%202013%2008%3A16%3A46%20GMT&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%221_1.pdf%22&x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzEKH//////////wEa4APgvaNTfkodsx1ZPzfXnPuUvk0ayGwAXwFg8gwHqwccUOCsDDpkfVvzwH8AU7fVxvbzsFtrpLGQuB9AtizamPfBWuQWyrgh%2B0Cyq0592PXXKF9ugeLBTSexGnYBCb9m%2BPXE5RAFi0bFhst/XAMbayyHpSqcvq/AaDFMHQ9DzphNXOkQeGXjUbSbuAJ3uAylsBAWEXmMJFxLbNdaBVJHl37wxoCspmaZxCA3MzR7a/2f/dOKrq1pbsoUM6bzfnjXwBIKyRThV/EzYj01z0SRNlb9s4cRDbmUudDXbdQdi%2BydclHqzbvQLghZ/AeV/2qDP/0tFJCa6Hx2iGv4PM/5aHkb2oDltX6zStPADFnBOFwzZgEI2IOjaJ0xrKlfHccu4HZ2hf44ZKI0EAXG6geyXIL1Lg%2BaJ0aAJMmaCVY5CbD%2Bn7M5Hc0na86o08MBPLZrQwUGIWz/kZ0nY39D2g0UsXfiaMNYodaVfGoZyzNbHJ18fSguRJyMfsxzStQNmgyPMEuZCpzAIOAi7QrEoyRefmEZ4XhyGZyOb6r3%2BeZYE5Nbb9QO3095gQnEkUHwqTSJlLkjNON5Nc9Pg79jq3QKs1hmgvwa%2BHGPywhlPyVL%2BWbsZ127TM%2BaIYZN0fa38IBCYVEg8a7ZkgU%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAJZYMKZB6NCYTAWXA&Signature=7HOURwBLdLLhh9y76THBctviC%2Bc%3D) . Perhaps Amazon has documentation on how you can avoid the html interface in order to retrive your file. I am not familiar with cloud drive at all. **Note that the url provided has some time limited token attached to it.**
2. Host the document on infrastructure you have more control over. IE. setup your own web server and host the documents there. Alternatively use another cloud storage provider which gives you the ability to link to files directly.

Comment: +1 I hosted the PDF file on my Amazon EC2 server through a virtual directory in IIS.  Thanks!